# Como usar um imgLoad antes de carregar a WebView

Tags: ios, swift

Em `swift` eu consigo carregar uma webView fazendo o seguinte:

1 - Adiciono UIWebView na minha View.

2 - Crio um Outlet chamado webView na minha viewcontroller.swift

3 - Insiro o seguinte código na minha função `viewDidLoad`

```
 let url = NSURL (string: "http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
 let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
 myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

Acontece que nesse loadRequest eu já estou chamando minha webView e funciona, porém não sei como posso adicionar uma imagem carregando para não deixar aquela tela em branco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemente o delegate de *UIWebView* para receber as mudanças de estado dela. Quando iniciar a carregar a webview você coloca algo na tela (imagem, activity indicator, HUD). Quando ela terminar de carregar, seja com sucesso ou com erro, você remove-o.

Por exemplo, para mostrar um imagem enquanto a webview carrega:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL (string: "https://pt.stackoverflow.com")
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj)
        myWebView.delegate = self
        addLoaderImage()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        removeLoaderImage()
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
        removeLoaderImage()
    }

    func addLoaderImage() {
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: myWebView.frame)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "loadingWebView.png")
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    func removeLoaderImage() {
        imageView.removeFromSuperview()
        imageView = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Tudo certo, adicionei um hub chamado MBProgressHUB no cocados coloquei o UIWebViewDelegate e  os dois métodos dele, so achei uma coisa ruim, ele realmente espera toda pagina carregar para sair o efeito do load, eu estou carregando um site do wordpress que e muito lento :(